# How can I parse and normalize HTML from different HTML generators?

Tags: html, perl, parsing

This is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981009/variables-in-perl-regex-not-working). I'm trying to parse HTML snippets embedded in an XML backup of a Blogger blog and retag them with InDesign tags.

Blogger doesn't standardize the HTML for any of its posts, and the posts can be written in Word, Windows Live Writer, the native Blogger interface, or text editors, resulting in tons of different forms of HTML. Some posts don't mark paragraphs and only use double `<br>`s in between paragraphs—others use actual `<p>` tags.

What's the best way to parse this unstandard conglomeration of tags?

Additionally, each post is not a complete HTML file--just a snippet that gets inserted into a template—which means that there is no overall HTML structure to parse (`<html><body></body></html>`, etc.) Does that have any effect on XML/HTML parsing?

Here's some potential examples, mostly standard HTML, missing paragraphs:

```
This is a section of a blog post. It has <a href="#">links</a> and lists and stuff. Weee....
<br>
<br>
Here's a list
<br/>
<br />
<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><ul>
And another paragraph here...
<br>
<br/>
Etc.
```

The Word HTML looks like this - http://www.timeatlas.com/mos/images/stories/word_html_tags.png

Comment: Can you post a reasonably sized snippet of the worst case input?

Comment: HTML parsing is easy with the right module. Are you really asking about how you would normalize it?

Comment: Yeah. At this point there are 4-5 different styles of HTML that can come through, so I'm wondering if I need to standardize/normalize/tidy the html first before traversing the DOM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML generated by Word is relatively easier to deal with. I would just get rid of all the tag attributes (unless you care about styles). That would live you with fairly plain HTML which you can then style.

[HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/HTML-TokeParser-Simple-3.15/) can help make that relatively painless.

As for the other stuff, that will take some trial and error. I am going to think more about that and post later if I can think of something clever.

**Later Update:**

Well, here is something that makes me cringe a little but it seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use Text::Markdown qw( markdown );

my $html = read_file \*DATA;

$html =~ s{(?:<br(:? ?/)*>)}{\n\n}g;

print markdown( $html );

__DATA__
This is a section of a blog post. It has <a href="#">links</a> and lists and stuff. Weee....
<br>
<br>
Here's a list
<br/>
<br />
<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>
And another paragraph here...
<br>
<br/>
```

Output:

```
<p>This is a section of a blog post. It has <a href="#">links</a> and lists and
stuff. Weee....</p>

<p>Here's a list</p>

<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>

<p>And another paragraph here...</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.60/Parser.pm)?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the other question, I like [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm).  It can handle both XML and HTML.

Comment: Can it take care of the untagged text and convert it to a real `<p>`? That's my main concern...

Comment: No, for that you need to use the same algorithm Blogger is using.

Comment: This is why I would use XML::LibXML, which has explicit support for repairing HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I tend to use XML::LibXML for all my XML and HTML needs.  Here is a one-liner that will convert a line of "bad" HTML into a well-formed XHTML document:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -ne 'my $p = XML::LibXML->new->parse_html_string($_); print $p->toString'
```

In your case, you probably want to use the DOM to emit a new document that has the correct tags.  This is straightforward; XML::LibXML uses the same W3C DOM that JavaScript does.

As an example, this input:

```
<p>Foo<p>Bar<br>Baz!
```

Gets translated into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Foo</p><p>Bar<br/>Baz!
</p></body></html>
```

This is probably what you want, and remember, use the DOM to translate... don't worry about this printed representation.

Comment: Cool. Is there any way to not get a full blown XML/HTML file and just get the <p>Foo</p><p>Bar<br/>Baz!</p>, or would I need to traverse the DOM to get just that out?

Comment: You need to traverse the DOM.